# reflesh ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi guys
i need some help here^^
i got a tag

```
 <html>
    <head>
    function clear_all(){
       $('#tag1').html('');
    }
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tag1"></div>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="clear_all();"/>
    </body>
```

assume all jquery is workable
 nw i use .ajax to change data in tag1, the value has changed 
but after that i not able to clear tag1's with function and jquery that i create
i only can change it with another ajax.
all ajax data is inside tag1
why i cannot clear tag1
thx

here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $('#' + form).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: ShowLoading,
                success: function(resp){
                    $('#theLoading').dialog('close');
                    $('#loading').html('');         
                    if(resp.status == 1){

                        $('.domtab').show();
                                                alert('run here');

                                                $('#tag1').html(
                                                    '<div style="width:1100px;margin-left:50px;"><div ><h1>'+resp.data.title+'</h1></div>'border:1px solid #333; white-space: nowrap">'+screen+'</div></div>'
                                                );
```

because its quite long, i shorten it into this
thx

Comment: can you paste your ajax code here?

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work. You probably have a bug elsewhere.

Comment: sure, i just edited my post, but my ajax is work, coz i can retrieve the data and post it, just i cannot clear it with

Comment: @Leon see http://jsfiddle.net/fa3NJ/

Comment: this `'<div style="width:1100px;margin-left:50px;"><div ><h1>'+resp.data.title+'</h1></div>'border:1px solid #333; white-space: nowrap">'+screen+'</div></div>'` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i wan to create another <div> inside #tag1, but i think i had solve the problem. THX for all your answer.... my error is cause by tag name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are unable to clear tag1 content after ajax because data inside tag was not present when DOM was loaded, data was added later via ajax, so u need to use `.live` to remove the content..

try below:

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="click" id="clearData"/>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){ 
    // u can also use $('#clearData').live(...);
    $('input[type="button"]').live('click',function(){
        $('#tag1').empty();                    
    });

});
```

**References**

#### [live](http://api.jquery.com/live)

#### [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Happy 2 Help :)